# Problem showing a limit ( involving the limit that equals the exponential function )

Tags: probability-theory, limits, probability-distributions

I am to show that if $(p_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence in (0,1) and $X_n\sim Bin(n,p_n)$ and $n\cdot p_n \to \lambda$ for $n\to \infty$ with $\lambda\geq0 $. Then
$$
X_n(P)=\mu_n \stackrel{w.k.}{\longrightarrow} \mu = X(P)
$$
where $X(P) \sim$Pois$(\lambda)$.

I want to show this by showing pointwise convergence of the characteristic function $\phi_n$ of $X_n$ to the characteristic function $\phi$ of $X$. So to show for all $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n(\theta)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+p_n(e^{i\theta}-1))^n = e^{\lambda(\exp(i\theta)-1)}=\phi(\theta)
$$
I know how to show $(1+x/n)^n\to e^x$ for $n\to\infty$, But in the current setup i am not sure show to formally use this together with $n\cdot p_n \to \lambda$ for $n\to \infty$, to show the above.

When i try to compute the limit, i seem to end up with a situation where i should L'Hopital, but i don't know the derivative of $p_n$ with respect to $n$. What to do? Can anybody show how this is done?